# Can I compose pointers to member

Tags: c++, composition, member-pointers

I'd like to compose member pointers. Basically I have a main class with different member. How do I create a member pointer for the main class that would point to a member of a member of that class. I hope the code below is explains what I'm trying to do:

```
  struct SubUnit
  {
    int   value;
  };
  struct Unit
  {
    SubUnit sub_unit;
  };

  void Test()
  {
    SubUnit Unit::* ptr1 = &Unit::sub_unit; // WORKING
    int Unit::* ptr2 = &Unit::sub_unit::value; // NOT WORKING !
  }
```

Comment: `::value` is an `int` but you're assigning it to a pointer to member?

Comment: You have to create a Unit object to have something to point to....ok, nevermind.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Not necessarily.

Comment: No, not like that at least. `value` is a member of `SubUnit`, not `Unit`.

Comment: this is how pointer to member works

Comment: I wonder what is it that you're trying to achieve. Think about pointers to members as offsets to a member from the "begginning" of the class. Also, you don't have a "subclass" there. It's a just a member object.

Comment: @jrok: Sorry I did not mean "subclass" but "a member of a member".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested data member pointer - not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439074/nested-data-member-pointer-not-possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of sub-class is confusing here, since generally sub-class is used for inheritance, so let us talk about a *data member*: `sub_unit` is a data member of `Unit`.

And what you are asking for is not possible, `Unit::*` can only represent an offset in either `Unit` itself or one of its base-classes:

```
struct SubUnit { int value; };

struct Unit: SubUnit {};

int main() { int Unit::* p = &Unit::value; }
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear, but in my case I'd rather use Composition over Inheritance.

Comment: @jules: the question is perfectly clear, and so is the answer: *not possible* (and btw, you are right to prefer Composition over Inheritance).

Comment: Better still, let's call it a *(data) member*, since that's the standard terminology.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have to do it in two phases:

```
SubUnit Unit::*pSub = &Unit::sub_unit;
int SubUnit::*pValue = &SubUnit::value;

Unit u;
int theVal = (u.*pSub).*pValue;
```

Comment: +1 no need to suspect otherwise, [as you are correct.](http://ideone.com/ZNQvsJ) I honestly think this deserves a better look from the OP.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for doing all the hard work :-). I'll remove the uncertainty from my answer.

Comment: No, thank *you*. I've never found the occasion to do it with *data members*, as the only need i've ever had was for member *functions*. It was educational.

Comment: Right, but you cannot pass this to a function that expects a 'int SubUnit::*' as an input...

Comment: @jules can't pass *what* to a function? Ultimately they're pointers-to-members. You need something to go *with* those members (i.e. objects) at each stage. Perhaps update your question with a specific example of what you're saying this does *not* address. It is conceivable what you ultimately want is simply not possible.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I want to store the pointer and bind them later to an object to extract the value. But the object comes later...

Comment: @jules Sure. but *which* object? If you're wanting to bind a `SubUnit::` member the object obviously needs to be a `SubUnit` or derivation therein. If the object is a `Unit` and the binding is a `SubUnit::` then either you need to expose the `SubUnit` from `Unit` or do what the code above does. Either way, I'm still unclear what the problem is. Sry. Code speaks volumes. There is no such thing as `int Unit::*` in your code, as there is no `int` members of that type. There is only `SubUnit Unit::*`, so that is what you have to work with.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a duplicate of this question:
[Nested data member pointer - not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439074/nested-data-member-pointer-not-possible)

The crux of the accepted answer says:

> A pointer-to-member can only be formed by an expression of type &qualified_id, which is not your case

The C++ standard says, in paragraph 8.3.3:
**Pointer to Members:**

> In a declaration T D where D has the form

```
  nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt D1
```

> and the nested-name-specifier denotes a class, and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list T”, then the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list cv
>   qualifier- seq pointer to member of class nested-name-specifier of type T”. 
>   The optional attribute-specifier-seq (7.6.1) appertains to the pointer-to-member.

It turns out, there's a way to do what you want, that seems to be working on my current compiler (apple llvm 5.0). However, *it is very implementation-dependant, and I would definitely recommend not using this solution in any kind of production code*:

```
//added a few data members to make it non-trivial
struct SubUnit {
    double d;
    int   value;
};
struct Unit {
    bool b;
    char c;
    SubUnit sub_unit;
};

intptr_t suOffset = offsetof(Unit, sub_unit);
intptr_t intOffset = offsetof(SubUnit, value);
intptr_t totalOffset = suOffset + intOffset;

// there is no way to convert this offset directly in a
// pointer-to-member AFAIK, so we have to trick a bit
int Unit::* pui = nullptr;
auto puiAddr = &pui;
intptr_t* puiAddrAsIntPtrPtr = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t*>(puiAddr);
*puiAddrAsIntPtrPtr = totalOffset;

//pui should now "point to the right offset"
//let's test it
Unit u;
u.sub_unit.value = 123456;

int val = u .* pui;
std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;
```

Comment: Well that's probably the right thing to do... Except that technically, in some cases, it actually is possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be constructed with a lambda:

```
    struct SubUnit
    {
        int   value;
    };
    struct Unit
    {
        SubUnit sub_unit;
    };

    void Test()
    {
        auto  composed_mem_ptr = [](Unit & unit) -> int&{ return  unit.sub_unit.value; };
        Unit  unit0{};
        composed_mem_ptr(unit0) = 7;
    }
```