# get and set values of a nested structure using external functions

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I am facing the following problem. I have a protected data structure `a map` of `<ID , Object>`. There is only one map data structure and multiple threads might want to `set` and `get` values from the map using an `ID`. The `Object` could be nested as shown in the following sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
struct C {
    int r;
    char s;
};
struct B {
    int p;
    char q;
    C c;
};
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    B b;
    char z;
};
/*
    A
    L__ x
    |
    L__ y
    |
    L__ B
        L__p
        |
        L__q
        |
        L__C
            L__r
            |
            L__s

*/
/*  the follwing is the
    data structure to store objects of of type A 
    corresponding to an ID (int)
*/
map<int,A> Map;
mutex m;

/*  Follwing are the desired 
    api's to set and get values from the Map 
    Locks are also required to handle concurrency
*/
void getValueFromMap(int id,/* what to pass ?? */) {
    m.lock();

    /* code to get the value of the specified varible */

    m.unlock();
}
void setValueInMap(int id,/* what to pass ?? */) {
    m.lock();

    /* code to set the new value to the specified variable */

    m.unlock(); 
}
int main() {
    /* lets suppose Map has some A type objects already */
    int id = 4;
    /* assume I want to change the information (value of p) of  id = 4*/
    /* instead of doing the following */
    m.lock();
    Map[id].b.p = 12; /*update to some value */
    m.unlock();
    /* what I need the follwing */
    setValueInMap(4,/* what_to_change , what_is_the_new_value etc .. */);

    /*similarly */

    /*if I want get the value of s */
    int s;
    m.lock();
    getValueFromMap(id,/* what_to_get,placeholder (for example &s) */);
    m.unlock();
}
```

I want to have some `api` calls ( for example `setValueInMap` with fixed number of arguments ) to `set` and `get` values of the `map` using function calls and all the mutex work will happen inside those `api` calls only. Although I have shown only one generic set function to set all types of member variables of `struct A`, it need not be (more api function calls is of no problem).

How it can be implemented?

thanks!

Comment: What about existing thread safe lock free map, it is usually based on skip list data structure. [libcdc](https://github.com/khizmax/libcds) have really good implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about making a generic function to act on map:

```
std::map<int, A> Map;
std::mutex m;

template <typename F>
auto ActOnMap(F&& f) -> decltype(f(Map)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(m);
    return f(Map);
}
```

(Note: you should probably create a class to structure that and hide direct access to `map` and `mutex`.)

And then:

```
/* lets suppose Map has some A type objects already */
int id = 4;
/* assume I want to change the information (value of p) of  id = 4*/
ActOnMap([id](std::map<int, A>&m){ m[id].b.p = 12;});

/*similarly */

/*if I want get the value of s */
int s = ActOnMap([id](std::map<int, A>&m){ return m[id].b.c.s;});
```

Answer (score 3):

The main question is how you want to encode what you call the "placeholder" into the C++ type system. To choose from:

- Plain indices (`0 -> A.x`, `3 -> B.q`, etc.) and some hardcoded switch statement (very fragile, not recommended).
- The same, but with an enum instead of indices. Not much better than above.
- Member variable pointers. This will get very awkward, especially due to the [nested structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439074/nested-data-member-pointer-not-possible).
- Functions. You can write access functions for each (nested) member and pass function pointers to those (or functors, e.g. lambdas). Something like this:

  ```
  void setBp(A& a, int value) { a.b.p = value; }
  // etc.

  template<typename T, typename SetterFunc>
  setValueInMap(int key, SetterFunc setterFunc, T value) {
    m.lock();
    setterFunc(Map[id], value);
    m.unlock();
  }

  // Usage
  setValueInMap(4, setBp, 12);
  ```

Note how none of these approaches is very pretty. At all. I'd look into changing the underlying design instead, the nested structure is really the root of this issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I also thought of having a function pointer table pointing to getter and setter functions for each member variables. I was not sure how to do it.

Comment: `nested structure is really the root of this issue.`
Why could be a better option ?

Comment: Possibly with member variable pointers and variadic template: `setValueInMap(42, 12, &A::b, &B::p)`

Comment: @Debashish: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18eb510e5483b22e)

Comment: @Max Langhof why the switch case method is "very fragile, not recommended" ?

Comment: @Debashish If members are added, removed, reordered or changed in any other way, you have to update every switch statement carefully. If you make a mistake with the indices the compiler has no chance to warn you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could go for a RapidJson approach or an if based (less elegant) approach:

```
(...)

void* getValueFromMap(int id, char structure, string item_name) {
    m.lock();

    if(structure == 'C') {
         if(item_name.compare("r") == 0) {
              return (void*) Map[id].B.C.r;
         } else if(...

    } else if(...

    m.unlock();
}
void setValueInMap(int id, char structure, string item_name, void* item) {
    m.lock();

    if(structure == 'C') {
         if(item_name.compare("r") == 0) {
              Map[id].B.C.r = (int) item;
         } else if(...

    } else if(...


    m.unlock(); 
}

int main() {
    int r;
    r = (int) getValueFromMap(4,'C',"r");

    setValueInMap(5,'C',"r",(void*) r);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I didn't compile this code, so it may have errors.

Comment: This is not tackling the issue. The question is about setting only specific members of each item.

Comment: Thanks! but.while `setting` values I might not have the complete object. Similarly, I may not want to copy the entire structure into a local copy outside. Because having a local copy of `A` in a `thread` is not a good idea for concurrency IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get it at first. I edited the answer and I hope it better answers it now.

Comment: Of course, this approach may be very time consuming for very big and nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could easily generate lambdas or functions to access nested members is to write a function or script to generate them in a scripting language.

```rb
# Ruby
def dig_lambda(*members)
  dig = "Map[id].#{members.join '.'}"  
  puts "[&]() -> decltype(#{dig}) {return #{dig};}" 
end

# prints [&]() -> decltype(Map[id].b.c.r) {return Map[id].b.c.r;}
dig_lambda %w[b c r]
```